# Install Ubuntu 18, keep grub on second hard drive

Tags: system-installation, windows, grub-efi

I'm looking to install Ubuntu on a separate laptop drive to Windows 10. I don't want Grub to manage my windows boot, I want to use the BIOS (UEFI) to choose the drive, on Drive 1 standard windows boot loader, on Drive 2 Grub, where I'm happy to select Ubuntu.

**Drive 1 128gb nvme**

`128 gb - Windows 10`

**Drive 2 500gb ssd**

```
256 - unallocated space, where I want to install both Grub and Ubuntu
```

**16GB ddr4 memory - relevant for swap?**

What would the recommended way of manually partitioning Drive 2 be to achieve this? I was thinking

```
30000 - /home ext4
4000 - /swap swap
221000 - / ext4
```

Will this work automatically, do I need to tell Grub where to go, if so how? Also, do I need a /var specifically? Better/easier way to do this?

Comment: It would be safest to disable the drive that you already have Windows installed on (either physically disconnect it, or through your BIOS). Also, you don't need a swap partition for Ubuntu 18; it will use a swap file automatically.

Comment: Good to know on swap. I agree disconnecting would be best, but is there a way not too, servicing this laptop is difficult, and I'm not sure I have a safe way to disable a hard drive in the bios either. Must be a way to tell Grub where to go.

Comment: Not with UEFI, grub wants to install into first ESP - efi system partition. Make sure drive is gpt partitioned. Most UEFI have a setting to, in effect, disconnect a drive.  You do not need nor want /boot, but suggest you have the ESP. And swap file now is standard, so no need for swap partition. I think you reversed /home & / (root) sizes. Your / only needs to be 25GB or so if separate /home. https://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: Well I just let grub take everything over... so far so good, I'm on Ubuntu and that's 95% of what counts : ' ), should I just close it, I think the answer is manual or nothing.